# How to print arabic text to a thermal printer from Flutter windows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, posprinter

I tried the Flutter package esc_pos_printer  to print to a thermal printer. It all works fine if I print Latin characters. I have tried using the mutilingual code page but it always fails when trying to print arabic characters. I need to be able to print in English, arabic, None of the available code pages in this package appear to support non Latin languages.
I am getting this error from the debugger

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters.: "Special 2: مرحبا بك"
#0      _UnicodeSubsetEncoder.convert (dart:convert/ascii.dart:85:9)
#1      Latin1Codec.encode (dart:convert/latin1.dart:40:46)
#2      Generator._encode
#3      Generator.text
#4      _MyAppState._printReceiveTest
<asynchronous suspension>
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters.: "Special 2: مرحبا بك"
#0      _UnicodeSubsetEncoder.convert (dart:convert/ascii.dart:85:9)
#1      Latin1Codec.encode (dart:convert/latin1.dart:40:46)
#2      Generator._encode
#3      Generator.text
#4      _MyAppState._printReceiveTest
<asynchronous suspension>
```

the code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pos_printer_platform/esc_pos_utils_platform/esc_pos_utils_platform.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pos_printer_platform/flutter_pos_printer_platform.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:dart_ping_ios/dart_ping_ios.dart';
import 'image_utils.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  // Register DartPingIOS
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    DartPingIOS.register();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // Printer Type [bluetooth, usb, network]
  var defaultPrinterType = PrinterType.bluetooth;
  var _isBle = false;
  var _reconnect = false;
  var _isConnected = false;
  var printerManager = PrinterManager.instance;
  var devices = <BluetoothPrinter>[];
  StreamSubscription<PrinterDevice>? _subscription;
  StreamSubscription<BTStatus>? _subscriptionBtStatus;
  StreamSubscription<USBStatus>? _subscriptionUsbStatus;
  StreamSubscription<TCPStatus>? _subscriptionTCPStatus;
  BTStatus _currentStatus = BTStatus.none;
  // ignore: unused_field
  TCPStatus _currentTCPStatus = TCPStatus.none;
  // _currentUsbStatus is only supports on Android
  // ignore: unused_field
  USBStatus _currentUsbStatus = USBStatus.none;
  List<int>? pendingTask;
  String _ipAddress = '';
  String _port = '9100';
  final _ipController = TextEditingController();
  final _portController = TextEditingController();
  BluetoothPrinter? selectedPrinter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (Platform.isWindows) defaultPrinterType = PrinterType.usb;
    super.initState();
    _portController.text = _port;
    _scan();

    // subscription to listen change status of bluetooth connection
    _subscriptionBtStatus =
        PrinterManager.instance.stateBluetooth.listen((status) {
      log(' ----------------- status bt $status ------------------ ');
      _currentStatus = status;
      if (status == BTStatus.connected) {
        setState(() {
          _isConnected = true;
        });
      }
      if (status == BTStatus.none) {
        setState(() {
          _isConnected = false;
        });
      }
      if (status == BTStatus.connected && pendingTask != null) {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
            PrinterManager.instance
                .send(type: PrinterType.bluetooth, bytes: pendingTask!);
            pendingTask = null;
          });
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          PrinterManager.instance
              .send(type: PrinterType.bluetooth, bytes: pendingTask!);
          pendingTask = null;
        }
      }
    });
    //  PrinterManager.instance.stateUSB is only supports on Android
    _subscriptionUsbStatus = PrinterManager.instance.stateUSB.listen((status) {
      log(' ----------------- status usb $status ------------------ ');
      _currentUsbStatus = status;
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        if (status == USBStatus.connected && pendingTask != null) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
            PrinterManager.instance
                .send(type: PrinterType.usb, bytes: pendingTask!);
            pendingTask = null;
          });
        }
      }
    });

    //  PrinterManager.instance.stateUSB is only supports on Android
    _subscriptionTCPStatus = PrinterManager.instance.stateTCP.listen((status) {
      log(' ----------------- status tcp $status ------------------ ');
      _currentTCPStatus = status;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _subscriptionBtStatus?.cancel();
    _subscriptionUsbStatus?.cancel();
    _subscriptionTCPStatus?.cancel();
    _portController.dispose();
    _ipController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // method to scan devices according PrinterType
  void _scan() {
    devices.clear();
    _subscription = printerManager
        .discovery(type: defaultPrinterType, isBle: _isBle)
        .listen((device) {
      devices.add(BluetoothPrinter(
        deviceName: device.name,
        address: device.address,
        isBle: _isBle,
        vendorId: device.vendorId,
        productId: device.productId,
        typePrinter: defaultPrinterType,
      ));
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void setPort(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) value = '9100';
    _port = value;
    var device = BluetoothPrinter(
      deviceName: value,
      address: _ipAddress,
      port: _port,
      typePrinter: PrinterType.network,
      state: false,
    );
    selectDevice(device);
  }

  void setIpAddress(String value) {
    _ipAddress = value;
    var device = BluetoothPrinter(
      deviceName: value,
      address: _ipAddress,
      port: _port,
      typePrinter: PrinterType.network,
      state: false,
    );
    selectDevice(device);
  }

  void selectDevice(BluetoothPrinter device) async {
    if (selectedPrinter != null) {
      if ((device.address != selectedPrinter!.address) ||
          (device.typePrinter == PrinterType.usb &&
              selectedPrinter!.vendorId != device.vendorId)) {
        await PrinterManager.instance
            .disconnect(type: selectedPrinter!.typePrinter);
      }
    }

    selectedPrinter = device;
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _generateImageFromString(
    String text,
    ui.TextAlign align,
  ) async {
    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = Canvas(
        recorder,
        Rect.fromCenter(
          center: Offset(0, 0),
          width: 550,
          height: 400, // cheated value, will will clip it later...
        ));
    TextSpan span = TextSpan(
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
      text: text,
    );
    TextPainter tp = TextPainter(
        text: span,
        maxLines: 3,
        textAlign: align,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout(minWidth: 550, maxWidth: 550);
    tp.paint(canvas, const Offset(0.0, 0.0));
    var picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final pngBytes = await picture.toImage(
      tp.size.width.toInt(),
      tp.size.height.toInt() - 2, // decrease padding
    );
    final byteData = await pngBytes.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Future _printReceiveTest() async {
    List<int> bytes = [];

    // Xprinter XP-N160I
    final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load(name: 'XP-N160I');

    // PaperSize.mm80 or PaperSize.mm58
    final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm58, profile);
    bytes += generator.setGlobalCodeTable('CP1252');
    bytes += generator.text('Test Print',
        styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left));
    bytes += generator.text('Product 1');
    bytes += generator.text('Product 2');
   

    bytes += generator.text(
        'Regular: aA bB cC dD eE fF gG hH iI jJ kK lL mM nN oO pP qQ rR sS tT uU vV wW xX yY zZ');
    bytes += generator.text('Special 1: àÀ èÈ éÉ ûÛ üÜ çÇ ôÔ',
        styles: PosStyles(codeTable: 'CP1252'));
    bytes += generator.text('Special 2: مرحبا بك',
        styles: PosStyles(codeTable: 'UTF-8'));

    bytes += generator.text('Bold text', styles: PosStyles(bold: true));
    bytes += generator.text('Reverse text', styles: PosStyles(reverse: true));
    bytes += generator.text('Underlined text',
        styles: PosStyles(underline: true), linesAfter: 1);
    bytes +=
        generator.text('Align left', styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left));
    bytes += generator.text('Align center',
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center));
    bytes += generator.text('Align right',
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.right), linesAfter: 1);

    bytes += generator.row([
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col6',
        width: 6,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
      PosColumn(
        text: 'col3',
        width: 3,
        styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center, underline: true),
      ),
    ]);

    // bytes += generator.text('￥1,990', containsChinese: true, styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left));
    // bytes += generator.emptyLines(1);

    // sum width total column must be 12
    bytes += generator.row([
      PosColumn(
          width: 8,
          text: 'Lemon lime export quality per pound x 5 units',
          styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left, codeTable: 'CP1252')),
      PosColumn(
          width: 4,
          text: 'USD 2.00',
          styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.right, codeTable: 'CP1252')),
    ]);

    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/ic_launcher.png');
    if (data.lengthInBytes > 0) {
      final Uint8List imageBytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
      // decode the bytes into an image
      final decodedImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes)!;
      // Create a black bottom layer
      // Resize the image to a 130x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
      img.Image thumbnail = img.copyResize(decodedImage, height: 130);
      // creates a copy of the original image with set dimensions
      img.Image originalImg =
          img.copyResize(decodedImage, width: 380, height: 130);
      // fills the original image with a white background
      img.fill(originalImg, color: img.ColorRgb8(255, 255, 255));
      var padding = (originalImg.width - thumbnail.width) / 2;

      //insert the image inside the frame and center it
      drawImage(originalImg, thumbnail, dstX: padding.toInt());

      // convert image to grayscale
      var grayscaleImage = img.grayscale(originalImg);

      bytes += generator.feed(1);
      // bytes += generator.imageRaster(img.decodeImage(imageBytes)!, align: PosAlign.center);
      bytes += generator.imageRaster(grayscaleImage, align: PosAlign.center);
      bytes += generator.feed(1);
    }

    // // Chinese characters
    bytes += generator.row([
      PosColumn(
          width: 8,
          text: '豚肉・木耳と玉子炒め弁当',
          styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left),
          containsChinese: true),
      PosColumn(
          width: 4,
          text: '￥1,990',
          styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.right),
          containsChinese: true),
    ]);
    _printEscPos(bytes, generator);
  }

  /// print ticket
  void _printEscPos(List<int> bytes, Generator generator) async {
    var connectedTCP = false;
    if (selectedPrinter == null) return;
    var bluetoothPrinter = selectedPrinter!;

    switch (bluetoothPrinter.typePrinter) {
      case PrinterType.usb:
        bytes += generator.feed(2);
        bytes += generator.cut();
        await printerManager.connect(
            type: bluetoothPrinter.typePrinter,
            model: UsbPrinterInput(
                name: bluetoothPrinter.deviceName,
                productId: bluetoothPrinter.productId,
                vendorId: bluetoothPrinter.vendorId));
        pendingTask = null;
        break;
      case PrinterType.bluetooth:
        bytes += generator.cut();
        await printerManager.connect(
            type: bluetoothPrinter.typePrinter,
            model: BluetoothPrinterInput(
                name: bluetoothPrinter.deviceName,
                address: bluetoothPrinter.address!,
                isBle: bluetoothPrinter.isBle ?? false,
                autoConnect: _reconnect));
        pendingTask = null;
        if (Platform.isAndroid) pendingTask = bytes;
        break;
      case PrinterType.network:
        bytes += generator.feed(2);
        bytes += generator.cut();
        connectedTCP = await printerManager.connect(
            type: bluetoothPrinter.typePrinter,
            model: TcpPrinterInput(ipAddress: bluetoothPrinter.address!));
        if (!connectedTCP) print(' --- please review your connection ---');
        break;
      default:
    }
    if (bluetoothPrinter.typePrinter == PrinterType.bluetooth &&
        Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (_currentStatus == BTStatus.connected) {
        printerManager.send(type: bluetoothPrinter.typePrinter, bytes: bytes);
        pendingTask = null;
      }
    } else {
      printerManager.send(type: bluetoothPrinter.typePrinter, bytes: bytes);
    }
  }

  // conectar dispositivo
  _connectDevice() async {
    _isConnected = false;
    if (selectedPrinter == null) return;
    switch (selectedPrinter!.typePrinter) {
      case PrinterType.usb:
        await printerManager.connect(
            type: selectedPrinter!.typePrinter,
            model: UsbPrinterInput(
                name: selectedPrinter!.deviceName,
                productId: selectedPrinter!.productId,
                vendorId: selectedPrinter!.vendorId));
        _isConnected = true;
        break;
      case PrinterType.bluetooth:
        await printerManager.connect(
            type: selectedPrinter!.typePrinter,
            model: BluetoothPrinterInput(
                name: selectedPrinter!.deviceName,
                address: selectedPrinter!.address!,
                isBle: selectedPrinter!.isBle ?? false,
                autoConnect: _reconnect));
        break;
      case PrinterType.network:
        await printerManager.connect(
            type: selectedPrinter!.typePrinter,
            model: TcpPrinterInput(ipAddress: selectedPrinter!.address!));
        _isConnected = true;
        break;
      default:
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Pos Plugin Platform example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: selectedPrinter == null || _isConnected
                                ? null
                                : () {
                                    _connectDevice();
                                  },
                            child: const Text("Connect",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 8),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: selectedPrinter == null || !_isConnected
                                ? null
                                : () {
                                    if (selectedPrinter != null)
                                      printerManager.disconnect(
                                          type: selectedPrinter!.typePrinter);
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isConnected = false;
                                    });
                                  },
                            child: const Text("Disconnect",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  DropdownButtonFormField<PrinterType>(
                    value: defaultPrinterType,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.print,
                        size: 24,
                      ),
                      labelText: "Type Printer Device",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    items: <DropdownMenuItem<PrinterType>>[
                      if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS)
                        const DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: PrinterType.bluetooth,
                          child: Text("bluetooth"),
                        ),
                      if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isWindows)
                        const DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: PrinterType.usb,
                          child: Text("usb"),
                        ),
                      const DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: PrinterType.network,
                        child: Text("Wifi"),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onChanged: (PrinterType? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (value != null) {
                          setState(() {
                            defaultPrinterType = value;
                            selectedPrinter = null;
                            _isBle = false;
                            _isConnected = false;
                            _scan();
                          });
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: defaultPrinterType == PrinterType.bluetooth &&
                        Platform.isAndroid,
                    child: SwitchListTile.adaptive(
                      contentPadding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0, left: 20),
                      title: const Text(
                        "This device supports ble (low energy)",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0),
                      ),
                      value: _isBle,
                      onChanged: (bool? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _isBle = value ?? false;
                          _isConnected = false;
                          selectedPrinter = null;
                          _scan();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: defaultPrinterType == PrinterType.bluetooth &&
                        Platform.isAndroid,
                    child: SwitchListTile.adaptive(
                      contentPadding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0, left: 20),
                      title: const Text(
                        "reconnect",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0),
                      ),
                      value: _reconnect,
                      onChanged: (bool? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _reconnect = value ?? false;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                      children: devices
                          .map(
                            (device) => ListTile(
                              title: Text('${device.deviceName}'),
                              subtitle: Platform.isAndroid &&
                                      defaultPrinterType == PrinterType.usb
                                  ? null
                                  : Visibility(
                                      visible: !Platform.isWindows,
                                      child: Text("${device.address}")),
                              onTap: () {
                                // do something
                                selectDevice(device);
                              },
                              leading: selectedPrinter != null &&
                                      ((device.typePrinter == PrinterType.usb &&
                                                  Platform.isWindows
                                              ? device.deviceName ==
                                                  selectedPrinter!.deviceName
                                              : device.vendorId != null &&
                                                  selectedPrinter!.vendorId ==
                                                      device.vendorId) ||
                                          (device.address != null &&
                                              selectedPrinter!.address ==
                                                  device.address))
                                  ? const Icon(
                                      Icons.check,
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                    )
                                  : null,
                              trailing: OutlinedButton(
                                onPressed: selectedPrinter == null ||
                                        device.deviceName !=
                                            selectedPrinter?.deviceName
                                    ? null
                                    : () async {
                                        _printReceiveTest();
                                      },
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 2, horizontal: 20),
                                  child: Text("Print test ticket",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList()),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: defaultPrinterType == PrinterType.network &&
                        Platform.isWindows,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _ipController,
                        keyboardType:
                            const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          label: Text("Ip Address"),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.wifi, size: 24),
                        ),
                        onChanged: setIpAddress,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: defaultPrinterType == PrinterType.network &&
                        Platform.isWindows,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _portController,
                        keyboardType:
                            const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          label: Text("Port"),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.numbers_outlined, size: 24),
                        ),
                        onChanged: setPort,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: defaultPrinterType == PrinterType.network &&
                        Platform.isWindows,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_ipController.text.isNotEmpty)
                            setIpAddress(_ipController.text);
                          _printReceiveTest();
                        },
                        child: const Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 50),
                          child: Text("Print test ticket",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothPrinter {
  int? id;
  String? deviceName;
  String? address;
  String? port;
  String? vendorId;
  String? productId;
  bool? isBle;

  PrinterType typePrinter;
  bool? state;

  BluetoothPrinter(
      {this.deviceName,
      this.address,
      this.port,
      this.state,
      this.vendorId,
      this.productId,
      this.typePrinter = PrinterType.bluetooth,
      this.isBle = false});
}
```